# Squish change python 2.4 on python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.4, squish

Discovered a problem - SQUISH is working with **python2.4**, but many necessary functions and libraries what i need - only in **python2.7**.

Support is over, and I can not ask for a version SQUISH with **python2.7**.

Somebody tell me the solution of this problem, or share the link to a version with integrated **python2.7** Squish.

Answer (score 1):

Even if support wasn't over, I'm not sure that this python version is a criteria for a new kit.
You can do this instead: download a version of **python 2.7** and install it to your localhost.
After you did this, open Squish and go to [*Edit* -> *Preferences* - *PyDev* -> *Interpreter* - *Python*] and choose the python.exe from where you installed it.
After you'll do this, Squish will add the new libraries from 2.7.

Close Squish and re-open it and you will have a SquishXX with python 2.7.

Comment: (Sorry for my bad english)Iugene, thanks for your answer, but i try do that many times - this is not help me. If i use "test.log(sys.version)" in squish script - i see python 2.4 ... So i can't use python 2.7 libs, they are not work.

Comment: Changing the Python version used by Squish binary packages
 If you want to use a more recent version of Python than the one bundled with Squish, and are using Linux or Windows, please contact Squish support since we may be able to provide a Squish binary package with the version of Python you want.

 FOR LINUX AND WINDOWS PLEASE NOTE!

 The Squish binary package that you use MUST BE BUILT WITH THE PYTHON VERSION THAT YOU WANT TO USE! (The default is Python 2.4.x.)

Comment: Strange! I am using Squish 5.0 that has build in python 2.4. In order to use python 2.7, which I needed it for some stuff, I did as I told you. It seems to work for me, without asking them for a newer version that has build-in 2.7.

Comment: Hm, if you try "import matplotlib" in squish - have you error?

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html This is not a standard python library. I can't use it at the moment in Squish, but neither in python console. In order for it to work, you have to do aditional imports to your python package.

Comment: I know this) thank you for your help, i find temp idea - use os.system('my_script_python2.7.py') in squish script

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the python Squish uses by setting **Scripting/PythonHome** in your SQUISHDIR/etc/paths.ini to the path of python you want to use.
More details in this links : http://kb.froglogic.com/display/KB/Changing+the+Python+installation+used+by+Squish+binary+packages